# Echo all json_encoded rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I'm trying to loop through my database and output all rows with a match to the joined table.

I have the following two tables:

**quest_items** stores all data related to an item:

[image]

**join_questitems** stores association between player ID and the items that player has:

[image]

**JS:** pass in all the necessary info to query the table...

```
$.getJSON("phpscripts.php", {
    "_player" : Player,
    "_playerID" : UserID
},
function(returned_data) {
    var item_name = returned_data.item_name;
    item_image = returned_data.item_image;

    $(".questItems").html(item_name + ", " + item_image);       
   }
);
```

**PHP:**

```
$statsArray = array();
$qry = 
    'SELECT qi.* 
    FROM quest_items qi
    LEFT JOIN join_questitems jqi ON (qi.item_id = jqi.item_id)
    WHERE jqi.user_id = "' . $playerID . '"';

$result = $mysqli->query($qry) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myrow = json_encode($row);
    array_push($statsArray, $myrow);
}   
$k = 0;
while ($k < count($statsArray)) {
    echo $statsArray[$k];
    $k++;
}
```

But if I just do one row, I get output, but only for one row. I need both rows:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo json_encode($row);
    exit;
}
```

`$(".questItems").html(item_name + ", " + item_image)` gives: `rice, test/path.png`

Why can't I loop through the PHP array full of json_encoded rows and output them? Do I have to set `item_name` and `item_image` as arrays and loop through the arrays?

---

EDIT:

- `$(".questItems").append(item_name + ", " + item_image)` doesn't work either
- network output from debugger shows rows are being output, but in the first row, my UTF-8 character, `fàn`, is being garbled in the client output (as you can see). This is curious, as at the top of my `phpscripts.php` file, I put `mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");`

[image]

Comment: now i see, you took my advice.

Comment: @Viscocent yes, sorry forgot to accept your answer. Thanks for that :) Just accepted.

Comment: I think instead of `.html()` you want `.append()` to append the text instead of override what is currently existing, no?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy see update above

Comment: it wont work because you are only returning the first row; since you used `exit` inside the loop.

Comment: @growler post the json as plain text so i can decode it with my json decoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't encode each row separately. Put all the results in an array, and then call `json_encode` on that array when you're done:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $statsArray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($statsArray);
```

Then in Javascript you need to loop over the returned array:

```
$.getJSON("phpscripts.php", {
    "_player" : Player,
    "_playerID" : UserID
},
    function(returned_data) {
        $.each(returned_data, function(i, e) {
            var item_name = e.item_name;
            var item_image = e.item_image;

            $(".questItems").append(item_name + ", " + item_image + "<br/>");       
        });
    };  
);
```

Comment: Can you explain the reason why I can't encode each row?

Comment: Because the result is not valid JSON. `$.getJSON` expects the response to be the JSON representation of a single object. You're returning multiple arrays, you need to collect them in an array, which means there must be `[]` around them.

Answer (score 1):

**rather than this:**

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo json_encode($row); 
    exit; //<--- this code breaks the while loop;
}
```

**have this:**

```
$quest_items = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $quest_items[] = $row;
}  

echo json_encode($quest_items);
exit;
```

because exit triggers the script to stop(even inside loops) so you will only get the first row.

Comment: You're only encoding the last row, and not doing anything with `$quest_items`.